# Facebook changes will break the Like plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, built-in

Is it true that the new implementation of the built-in like button will break current Like button plugin? Because from Developers roadmap page of facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ it says that on October 3 2012

'We will stop allowing the use of Custom Open Graph "like" and "follow" actions now that there are built-in "like" and built-in "follow" actions. Please convert any custom "like" or "follow" actions you may have created to instead use the built-in "like" or "follow" actions.'

Am I right that the current like plugin will not be supported or will not work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

This have nothing to do with Facebook Like Button social plugin.

Changes described in RoadMap is about OpenGraph actions that mimic "Like" alike behavior and need to be replaced with built-in action created by Facebook.

Like Button social plugin will not be affected by those changes and should continue to work as expected.